# Issue starting h2o from RStudio, running command 'curl 'http://localhost:54321'' had status 127

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o

I'm trying to start H2O from within RStudio. I've got the latest versions of R, RStudio, the R H2O package, Java SE SDK and the RCurl package. But when trying to initialize H2O, I get the following output:

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:

 C:\Users\fel069\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQZJyS1/h2o_fel069_started_from_r.out
 C:\Users\fel069\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQZJyS1/h2o_fel069_started_from_r.err

java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

    Starting H2O JVM and connecting:     ............................................................ 
[1] "localhost"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1
[1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"
[1] 127
Error in h2o.init(nthreads = -1, max_mem_size = "8g") : 
  H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'curl 'http://localhost:54321'' had status 127
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Branden is right. I assumed that any similar questions would have showed up on Google. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I overlooked the requirements of H2O. Java 9 SDK is not supported. Downgrading to version 8 fixed my problem.