# Error installing h20 in R

Tags: r, installation

I have this error in installing the h2o package in R. Please see below

```
     Error in h2o.init() : H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
      In addition: Warning message:
     running command 'curl 'http://localhost:54321'' had status 127 

    Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:

    java version "9.0.1"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

   Starting H2O JVM and connecting: 
  ............................................................ 
   [1] "localhost"
   [1] 54321
   [1] TRUE
   [1] -1
   [1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"
   [1] 127
```

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: It seems JDK 9 is not supported. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535110/issue-starting-h2o-from-rstudio-running-command-curl-http-localhost54321

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with H2O in R - can't connect to local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392394/error-with-h2o-in-r-cant-connect-to-local-host)